# Chopping out last field of the output of find?

Tags: linux

How can I chop out the text, returned by **find**, after the last "/" ?

```
$ find home/a/misc/ -type f
home/a/misc/6
home/a/misc/5
home/a/misc/2
```

I can do it by piping `cut -d"/" f4` to the find command but problem is that the folder **misc**
folder is not always there in folder **a**. It can be in like **/home/a/b/c/d/e/**. In that case it will return the element in folder **c**

**Edit:**
6, 5 and 2 are files, not directories.

**Solved**

using **-printf %f** with the **find** command did the magic. Thanks to all of you

Comment: I am somewhat confused about your question. Can you show a few examples of the input that you have, and the output that you want? From my interpretation of your original question, it sounds like `basename` is exactly what you are looking for, so I think I'll need some clarification to be able to help you further.

Comment: Thanks Brian. No need now. -print %f with the find command did the work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`basename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/basename) will do the trick:

```
$ basename foo/bar
bar
$ find . -type f
./bar/quux/file
./foo/bar
./foo/baz
$ find . -type f -exec basename {} \;
file
bar
baz
```

Comment: actually 6, 5 and 2 are files...not directories

Comment: Nah..that gives following error
basename: extra operand `/home/a/misc/2'

Comment: Never mind my previous comment; the problem was probably that I used `xargs` in my example, which works differently on Linux and Mac OS X. With `find -exec` this should work a little better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use basename or dirname